# Cannot create a new flutter project, run emulator and many more issues on the IDE (Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, plugins, sdk, flutter-doctor

i can't create a new flutter project with android studio.
as soon as i click "new project" the ide starts loading endlessly.
also if I open a random project device manager, flutter doctor don't work and the error "android sdk file not found in platform/android-29" appears.
Could it be an SDK related issue? (Android, dart, flutter)

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky8aH.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU8Ra.png)

Initially I accidentally installed Android Studio 2 times: one from zip and one through intellij toolbox.
of course I uninstalled the one from the toolbox and completed the installation of the other one.
When the problem started I installed and uninstalled the ide and plugins (flutter and dart) over and over again, and cleared the cache.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the issues you are experiencing with Android Studio and Flutter are related to the SDK configuration or installation. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the problems:

1. SDK Installation and Configuration:

   a. Ensure that you have installed the Android SDK correctly. Open Android Studio, go to `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK` and check that the SDK is properly installed and configured.

   b. Make sure you have installed the necessary SDK platforms and system images. Ensure that you have installed the Android 29 SDK platform and associated system images.

   c. Verify that the SDK path is set correctly in Android Studio. Go to `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK` and check that the SDK location is correct.
2. Flutter and Dart SDK Installation:

   a. Check that you have installed Flutter and Dart SDKs correctly. Follow the instructions from the official Flutter website to install them.

   b. Set the Flutter SDK path in Android Studio. Go to `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter` and make sure the Flutter SDK path is correctly set.
3. Project SDK Configuration:

   a. If you are unable to create a new Flutter project, check that your Flutter and Dart plugins are enabled in Android Studio. Go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins` and verify that both Flutter and Dart plugins are enabled.
4. Cache and Plugin Issues:

   a. Clear the cache in Android Studio. Go to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` and choose "Invalidate and Restart" to clear the cache.

   b. Reinstall the Flutter and Dart plugins. Uninstall them from `File -> Settings -> Plugins`, then reinstall them.
5. Use Stable Versions:

   a. Make sure you are using stable versions of Flutter and Dart. Avoid using beta or dev channel versions for production development.
6. Check System Environment:

   a. Ensure that your system environment variables are set correctly for Flutter and Dart. The `flutter` and `dart` commands should be accessible from the command line.
7. Check Anti-Virus and Firewall Settings:

   a. Sometimes, anti-virus or firewall settings may interfere with the installation and operation of Android Studio and Flutter. Check if any anti-virus or firewall software is blocking the IDE or its processes.

If the above steps do not resolve the issues, consider doing a clean uninstall of Android Studio and Flutter, then reinstall them from scratch following the official documentation.

Comment: thank you so much, i've tried all the steps but nothing worked.
so i clean deleted everything.
I'd vote up for your comment if i could

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm sorry for you brother.